# Simple estimation of separation of powers of 2 and powers of 3?

Tags: estimation, diophantine-approximation, transcendence-theory

An accepted answer is in the cross post at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428396/simple-estimation-of-difference-of-powers-of-2-and-powers-of-3 .

**1. Question**

How to get from the formulas

$$ \left| \frac{\log 2}{\log 3} - \frac{p}{q} \right| < c_a\frac{1}{q^{B_a}} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1.1)$$

and / or

$$ \left| \frac{\log 2}{\log 3} - \frac{p}{q} \right| \geq c_b\frac{1}{q^{B_b}} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1.2)$$

to the formula

$$ \left| 3^p - 2^q \right| \geq c_r\frac{1}{q^{B_r}}3^p\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1.3)$$

with constants $c_a, c_b, B_a, B_b \in \mathbb{R}$ given and $\frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}$?

It is also important for me how exactly $c_r, B_r \in \mathbb{R}$ depend on the other constants $c_a, c_b, B_a$, and $B_b$. All 6 constants are > 0 and $B_a, B_b \in [2, 8)$.

The lower bound in (1.3) is claimed by https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/08/21/hilberts-seventh-problem-and-powers-of-2-and-3/ (proposition 3 and corollary 4) . Terry Tao uses (1.2) with $\geq$ instead of (1.1) with $<$. Maybe both inequalities are required to prove (1.3) for the two cases $3^p > 2^q$ and $3^p < 2^q$.

Something very similar is [the answer by user Lierre to the MO question distance between powers of 2 and powers of 3](https://mathoverflow.net/a/116844/163727), but I would like to see more detailed steps and how to calculate the constants in (1.3).

**2. Ansatz A**

\begin{align}
3^p - 2^q &= 3^p - (3^{\log_3(2)})^q\\
          &= 3^p - 3^{q\cdot \log_3(2)}\\
          &= 3^p - 3^{q\cdot \log_3(2) - p + p}\\
          &= 3^p - 3^p\cdot3^{q\cdot \log_3(2) - p}\\
          &= 3^p - 3^p\cdot3^{q\cdot(\log_3(2) - \frac{p}{q})}\\
          &= 3^p(1 - 3^{q\cdot(\log_3(2) - \frac{p}{q})}) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2.1)\\
\end{align}

Note that

\begin{align}
3^p > 2^q &\iff \log_3(3^p) > \log_3(2^q)\\
          &\iff p > q\log_3(2)\\
          &\iff \frac{p}{q} > \log_3(2)\\
          &\iff 0 > \log_3(2) - \frac{p}{q}\\
          &\iff \log_3(2) - \frac{p}{q} < 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2.2)\\
\end{align}

and analogously

$$2^q > 3^p \iff \log_3(2) - \frac{p}{q} > 0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2.3)$$.

**3. Ansatz B**

\begin{align}
3^p - 2^q &= 3^p(1 - \frac{2^q}{3^p})\\
          &= 3^p(1 - \frac{(e^{\log2})^q}{(e^{\log3})^p})\\
          &= 3^p(1 - \frac{e^{q\log2}}{e^{p\log3}})\\
          &= 3^p(1 - e^{q\log2 - p\log3}) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3.1)\\
\end{align}

Comment: @Lily White thanks for the enhancement and sorry, we were editing at the same time. I've now put your suggested edit back in.

Comment: I still have no proof, but maybe that conjecture of mine is worth to be considered to be proved: ${1\over\ c \cdot  N \cdot \ln N} \lt q \ln2 - p \ln3 $ (with $c\approx 10$, $p \gt 3$. I checked this up to $p$ with a million dec digits (from convergents of cont.frac. of $\log_2(3)$. *This very idea has been inspired  by playing with trunctations of the mercatorseries for $\ln (1+x)$ and $x=1$ or $2$ when difference went to $\varepsilon$. Unfortunately I couldn't bring this idea to a constructive result, but my estimate came from that heuristics. Just to give some background)*

Comment: An accepted answer is in the cross post at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428396/simple-estimation-of-difference-of-powers-of-2-and-powers-of-3 .

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Is the $N$ in $\frac{1}{c \cdot N \cdot \log(N)}$ one of $p$ or $q$? I believe your formula is already proved, but the bounds are not effectively computable. I.e. we can't calculate the c. We only know that it exists.

Answer (score -1):

The logarithms of $2^n$ and $3^m$ can be arbitrarily close together for n, m > 0. That doesn’t mean the numbers themselves get close.

Comment: Your answer is actually a comment. You should use the commenting feature for such.